# Get a daterange in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

Im working on an application in extJS4 and i need to enter 2 values: startdate and enddate.

Both of them require an Ext.Date object.

[Link to the date object](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date)

What i want is for the startdate to be todays date minus 4 months and enddate should be todays date plus 4 months. Anyone know how i can achieve that?

Also would i be possible to get these values through an ajax call. So i can define them somewhere else and do an ajax call for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's example of using Date.add right there in the docs you linked:

```
var d = new Date(),
    eDate = Ext.Date,
    start = eDate.add(d, eDate.MONTH, -4),
    end = eDate.add(d, eDate.MONTH, 4);
```